# Objective c time delay

Tags: objective-c, delay, nstimer

Here is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction) startApproximiteLevel:(id)sender {
[getBackgroundLevel startAnimation:self];
float sample1;
float sample2;
float sample3;
float sample4;
float sample5;
float finalSample;

float charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel floatValue];

sample1 = charlieSoundVolume;
sleep(1)
sample2 = charlieSoundVolume;
sleep(1)
sample3 = charlieSoundVolume;
sleep(1)
sample4 = charlieSoundVolume;
sleep(1)
sample5 = charlieSoundVolume;
sleep(1);
finalSample = ((sample1 + sample2 + sample3 + sample4 + sample5) / 5);
self.backgroundSoundChange.floatValue = finalSample;

[getBackgroundLevel stopAnimation:self];
```

}

But this will stop another part of my code from updating the charlieSoundLevel. Any idea on how to do this without the sleep()?

Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `[NSObject performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` to launch a method on the run loop after a certain amount of time.

Comment: At some point you'll need to be able to read and understand the documentation, rather than rely on others to write your code for you.

Comment: I did, I can't find any info on using a "time delay" with this. PLEASE can someone post code. Believe me, I'm not a slacker...

Comment: If you look at the documentation you can see the "related sample code" section.